# Markdown renderer doesn't accept é or ö in links

Tags: bug, status-completed, hyperlinks, editor

e.g.:

### Source

```
[This link will merge with the text and the 2nd link][1]

non-link text

[this link causes the previous link to merge with it.][2] 

[1]: http://example.com/ 
[2]: http://example.com/áéíóúö/
```

### Demonstration

[This link will merge with the text and the 2nd link](http://example.com/)

non-link text

[this link causes the previous link to merge with it.](http://example.com/%C3%A1%C3%A9%C3%AD%C3%B3%C3%BA%C3%B6/)

### Description

Note that there are client side and server side bugs with this.

**Server side:** when rendered the above is one link, pointing to http://example.com/
**Client side:** when previewed only the first link is linked.

I'm primarily concerned about the foreign alphabet characters since they are the most frequently used, not other glyphs that [may be used in URLs](http://i-technica.com/whitestuff/urlencodechart.html).

### Possible workarounds

As I've [said elsewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/217533/links-to-urls-containing-parentheses/258369#258369):

> Sometimes URLs can fail to link correctly because they contain disallowed characters. In these cases [encode the characters using the % notation](http://i-technica.com/whitestuff/urlencodechart.html). Previously characters such as () [] ' and * were not allowed but the server-side Markdown renderer has been modified to accept them now. Currently the only (known) characters that aren't accepted are ones with accents, graves, diaeresis etc. For example: é or ö, although **with wikipedia links** you can just use the unadorned character.

Comment: crazy moon language!

Comment: This is Jeff's sneaky way of trying to force everyone into an English-dominated world.

Comment: I'm sure someone will be along shortly with a Greasemonkey solution.

Comment: HURRY UP JONATHAN!

Comment: See Jeff, you used RegEx, and now you've got two problems.

Comment: well, three, counting you

Comment: Touche, good sir. Could you post how you solve this, though? I've yet to do RegEx on anything but the standard US alphabet, so I'm intrigued at the ranges you need to use to include the rest of the world as well as thwart potentially dangerous URLs/code.

Answer (score 3):

You can place such links using the link insertion toolbar button, aka <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>.

```
http://example.com/áéíóúö/
```

inserted as stated above:

[link text goes here](http://example.com/%C3%A1%C3%A9%C3%AD%C3%B3%C3%BA%C3%B6/)

Answer (score 1):

If you use numeric or named html entity references it seems to work code as above but with some of these in [2], don't know if this is an easier workaround or not.

```
  [2]: http://example.com/&atilde;&#226;&#227;/
```

[This link will merge with the text and the 2nd link](http://example.com/)

non-link text

[this link causes the previous link to merge with it.](http://example.com/ãâã/)