# Why does the markdown editor not display my link properly and why do I need to insert my own linebreaks?

Tags: bug, status-completed, hyperlinks, editor

I am having some problems with the markdown editor.

Could someone explain me why this link doesn't work?

This should be a link:
[0.25 €/kwh * 650W * 1 month](http://www00.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=0.25+%E2%82%AC/kwh+*+650W+*+1+month)

It should be linking to:

> `http://www00.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=0.25+€/kwh+*+650W+*+1+month`

Another problem that I often have is that when I want to write on the next line I need to insert my own line breaks (`<br />`).

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4772/markdown-renderer-doesnt-accept-eor-oin-links

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the line break issue:
Look at the [editor help](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help). You just need to include two spaces at the end of the line.

For the link issue:
Obviously there are some unescaped characters in that text. I would recommend not linking that text anyway. That is messy.

Comment: I missed the editor help. The linebrak is not so intuitive, the inline linking is great! Thanks.

Comment: @Andrea: How about accepting my answer?

Comment: I was waiting an answer from Jeff, but he didn't reply!

Answer (score 1):

This particular link is so awkward and contains so many oddball chars I would recommend using TinyURL or the like.

Some URLs are just too difficult to parse. My "favorite" is URLs that actually contain http:// as part of the querystring..

**Edit:** Note that the escaping will be done automatically for you if you use the link button (or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>L</kbd>).

[here's the troublesome Wolfram link from the question, entered using Ctrl+L](http://www00.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=0.25%20%E2%82%AC/kwh%20*%20650W%20*%201%20month)

Comment: Is there a particular reason to don't match *€$ ?