# Consistent Handling of Illegal URLs

Tags: feature-request, editor

As expressed in relevant answers here on meta (questions [6808](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6808/possible-link-bug/6810#6810) and [11581](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11581/link-parser-chokes-on-url/11626#11626)) there are URLs which are illegal to use in questions and answers. The system should be enhanced to address those URLs in two ways:

- The editor **preview** should fail to render them correctly, which it currently does, since this gives the false impression everything would be ok.
- The editor **help** should be enhanced to warn about illegal URLs, state what is legal and what is not, and advise the user to use alternative URLs (e.g. those obtained by URL shortener services like tinyurl.com etc.), or %-encoding of offending characters, if he needs to use them.

Comment: I often wish that I could get a _real_ preview of questions or answers before I post them.

Comment: If these urls: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4772/markdown-renderer-doesnt-accept-eor-oin-links aren't going to be handled then they could also have their own help prompts.

Comment: I'm not so sure, Sam. I can't say off the top of my head, but I suspect the URI RFC prohibits the kinds of characters in URLs which your question targets. I'm not so sure about the ":" character (in my case) either...

Comment: ":" needs escaping: http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3986#section-2.2

Comment: I'm pretty sure that it takes the same amount of effort to notify you if a url *is* illegal as it does to modify the illegal url *into* a legal one. Why add support to tell you what you *can't* do when you could add support to make it possible?

Comment: @Ian If you follow the links in my question and see the tone of the answers they link to, you probably understand the direction of this question. It's also not about notification, in the sense of interactive help or something, but about static text as in the editor's side bar or linked from there. And the fact that the editor preview mirrors the post with all its flaws as it will appear when submitted.